# In Angular 8 Server Side Rendering or Build Production is not Working when ivy is enabled

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, angular8, server-side-rendering

Due to the introduction of **Ivy** in Angular 8 I cannot harness its capability.
When Ivy is disabled it is working fine.

tsconfig.app

"angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableIvy": false
    }

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately it will be available to render on server with combination Ivy in version 9! But, you can use v9-next(unstable) if that is no problem for you. If I were you I would wait for about a month and v9 stable will be released.

Comment: No problem.  If you think it helped you, you can upvote answer :)